# Adding evm chain id to ethereum list

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, registration, ipfs, chain

I have been working on EVM integrated relay chain  in substrate . I want to register  my chain  ID on ethereum chain and my checkmarks are not getting verified there . i want to know about the steps to add my chains EVM id to ethereum  chain lists.

i have followed steps mentioned in the above document [chainid](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains)